# How to create a content/post and post it on Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn simultaneously using Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm developing a cross platform app (ios and android) using Nativescript-Vue. One of the features we want to implement is to have a UI where a user can create a simultaneous post to Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn. There are specific Nativescript plugin for these social medias, but It can not be done using these plugins since these displays a dialog where the user can login or create a post. Is there a better way to implement this feature using Nativescript-Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not share to different social media apps simultaneously, not without user interaction.

You may use [nativescript-social-share](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-social-share) plugin, this should show all available apps on the device that is capable of sharing the given content. User will have to manually choose which application he wants and share there. If user wants to share on multiple apps, then he would have to repeat the process multiple times.

If you really want to make the process easy for user to share over multiple apps upon single click, it's not an easy job to do. You will have to integrate SDK from each social platform, acquire permissions / access tokens form user, keep the tokens with you (on device or server) so you can automatically share the content via appropriate SDKs with valid tokens.

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thanks for your  answer. I agree on your  latter point. It requires a lot of work to accomplish this functionalities. Do you have any source of information that can help me to accomplish this?

Comment: In that case your question is too broad. You have to go one step at a time, review each and every social media SDK and integrate. For example with Facebook, there is [nativescript-facebook](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-facebook) plugin that helps to acquire permissions & token, once you have token you can write to user feed programatically. There are login plugins for Twitter & LinkedIn, but I'm unsure about share functionality, you will have to review the official iOS / Android SDKs and take it forward.

Comment: I've already installed nativescript-facebook plugin, and I successfully integrated it. But, it uses dialogs as their  UI. I examined its documentation on github if there is a way to make my own custom UI and add share functionality without showing a dialog but I found none. Is this possible with nativescript-facebook?    Anyway, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with Facebook recently, but looking at their docs it seems the permissions to write on user's wall has been removed. The only way Facebook allows you to share a post is via the dialog.